# Qual código utilizo para compartilhar no facebook o conteúdo de uma página com foto, título e descrição específica?

Tags: html, facebook

Preciso compartilhar no facebook o conteúdo de uma página com foto, título e descrição específica, como faço?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Na realidade, isso não é nem php e nem css, mas sim html!

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Título" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Descrição" />
<meta property="og:image" content="Link_da_Imagem" />
```

Basta colocar isso no seu head, e alterar o atributo **content** de cada tag. O primeiro é o título, o segundo a descrição e o terceiro é o link da imagem.

No caso, você adicionará isso na página que será compartilhada, as vezes leva um tempo para o Facebook notar!

PS: Sugiro que faça uma pesquisa mais completa da próxima vez, se você jogar sua pergunta no Google, vai achar o que precisa.